# How to reference history records from inner query

Tags: apex, soql

I'm trying to find field history information for a few fields that I'm querying inside a loop. This is what I'm doing :

```
Set<String> setHistoryFields = new Set<String>{'ASIN__c','Channel__c'};
SELECT ASIN__c, Channel__c, (SELECT ParentId, OldValue, NewValue,
Field, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate FROM Histories WHERE Field IN:
setHistoryFields ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM
Custom_Object__c
```

I need to have the LastModifiedBy(CreatedBy.Name) and LastModifiedDate(History record's CreatedData) so that I can show the same on UI along with the 2 fields.

How do I access the fields from the inner query and update in wrapper variables.

Any other approach that I can take? Any help would be much appreciated here.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is similar to the one asked at: 
[Last modified by of custom field](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/215638/last-modified-by-of-custom-field/215640#215640)

You should first enable field history tracking for your custom object. Then add the field that you want to track. Then run the query: SELECT ParentId, OldValue, NewValue, Field, CreatedBy.Name, CreatedDate FROM CustomObject__History where Field = 'CustomField__c'.

For more info: please visit https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=tracking_field_history_for_custom_objects.htm&type=5

Comment: How to access I understand.. but how do I assign them to instance variables is the question here.. So the point is how do i access the inner query variables if I'm using the query in for loop looping value.

Comment: May I ask why you need to use an inner query? Is it absolutely necessary for your case?

Comment: Yes, for every record I need the field history data for a few fields which I then have to show on the UI. I could not think of any other way to do this but inner query as it would fetch me the field history data for every record on every iteration.

Comment: Would this work for you? SELECT Name, customfield__c, (SELECT OldValue, NewValue FROM Histories ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1) FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE customfield__c IN :setHistoryFields

Answer (score 0):

You iterate over the child collection.

```
for (MyObject__c record : [/*query*/])
{
    for (MyObject__History history : record.Histories)
    {
        String field = history.Field;
        // and so on
    }
}
```